# Calculate new graph point with coordinate and angle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

On a Cartesian graph I have a point at $x = 0$ and $y = 0$. This point needs to move forward at a $30^\circ$ angle. It should travel forward at this angle for $1.75$ on the graph. What equation can I use to do this?

Summary:

- Cartesian graph point $(0, 0)$
- Moves forward at a $30^\circ$ angle
- Needs to travel forward at the angle $1.75$ on the graph
- Is there an equation for this?

Comment: I suggest you read up on [trigonometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry)

Comment: Thanks captain obvious. But I'm just getting back into math after a very long time.

Comment: Looks like (sin( angle * pie / 180) * 1.75) worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There *is* an way to determine the coordinates of the point. I assume that you mean "moves $1.75$ units *along a line in the first quadrant that makes a $30$ degree angle with the positive x-axis*", or something like that.

Draw a reference right triangle [image]

This one is pretty sloppy... learn "SOHCAHTOA", a mnemonic device for trig ratios. Then we can say
$$\cos(30) = x/1.75  $$

$$\sin(30) = y/1.75$$
And solve for x, y.

Comment: your missing (angle * pie / 180) * 175